# How can I make this sql query to work on the fist way?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Here is my SQL query. I have a table A, but when I try to use this table into HAVING (A.CATEGORY) show me an error `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`. On the other way it works if I copy all code from table A at the same place. How can I make this query to work fine on the fist way? Thanks

FIRST(NOT CORRECT):

```
SELECT
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO,
    (SELECT
        DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY
     FROM
        DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO
    HAVING
        MAX(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
        = (SELECT MAX(MAX(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE)) 
             FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO 
            GROUP BY DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY)
    GROUP BY
        DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY) A
WHERE
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY = A.CATEGORY
HAVING
    MIN(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
    = (SELECT MIN(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
        FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO 
       WHERE DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY = A.CATEGORY 
       GROUP BY DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY)
GROUP BY
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.PRODUCT_NAME
```

SECOND(CORRECT):

```
SELECT
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO,
    (SELECT
        DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY
     FROM
        DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO
    HAVING
        MAX(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
        = (SELECT MAX(MAX(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE)) 
             FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO 
            GROUP BY DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY)
    GROUP BY
        DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY) A
WHERE
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY = A.CATEGORY
HAVING
    MIN(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
    = (SELECT MIN(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
        FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO 
       WHERE DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY 
             = (SELECT DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY
                  FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO
                HAVING MAX(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
                       = (SELECT MAX(MAX(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE)) 
                            FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO 
                           GROUP BY DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY)
                 GROUP BY DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY) 
       GROUP BY DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY)
GROUP BY
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.PRODUCT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% of what you're trying to do, but the error is because of this section of your script:

```
HAVING
    MIN(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
    = (SELECT MIN(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
        FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO 
       WHERE DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY = A.CATEGORY 
       GROUP BY DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY)
```

`select min(ilst_price)...group by category` will produce a list of list_prices.  So effectively the `having` clause is saying "only the rows in which the minimum list_prices **equals** the list of minimum list_prices, grouped by category".  This, of course, is illogical.

I assume you want the minimum list_price for the category?  You will need to remove the `group by`.  Also, the `min()` around list_price needs to be on the outside of the inner select.  Here's a complete working version:

```
SELECT
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO,
    (SELECT
        DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY
     FROM
        DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO
    HAVING
        MAX(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
        = (SELECT MAX(MAX(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE)) 
             FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO 
            GROUP BY DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY)
    GROUP BY
        DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY) A
WHERE
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY = A.CATEGORY
HAVING
    MIN(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE) 
    = MIN((SELECT MIN(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE)
        FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO 
       WHERE DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.CATEGORY = A.CATEGORY))
GROUP BY
    DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.PRODUCT_NAME
```

Comment: If I remove GROUP BY, show me the same error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

I am trying to use A.CATEGORY.. But A.CATEGORY don't work inside.. How I can use "A" table into having?

Comment: There was another problem -- the `MIN()` in your `HAVING` clause needs to go outside of the `SELECT`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Error again:

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Difficult to debug without seeing the data... but try `MIN((SELECT MIN(DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO.LIST_PRICE)...`.  If it works, I'll update my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY clause goes before the HAVING clause. This is the correct order:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
HAVING ...
```

Comment: Oracle will accept `HAVING` before `GROUP BY`: `select sum(1) from dual having sum(1) > 1 group by dummy` will work.